# Numerical value input in cocos2d

Tags: ios, user-interface, cocos2d-iphone

I created a configuration scene for my game using cocos2d menus, but I want to be able to allow the user to enter numerical values.

Menus are great for multiple choice stuff, but how can I add a value box or other way for the user to enter numerical values.

Comment: Ouch! Josh, it was a bit harsh to downvote me for wrong tags. I am new to SO and I lost 2 of my valuable 6 points. Anyway, why did you remove the Cocos2d tags?

Comment: I most certainly didn't downvote because you had wrong tags. You should never assume here that you know who downvoted or why -- the anonymity of voting is by design and fiercely guarded. I removed the tag because it's not clear how Cocos2d applies to your question; you're asking about GUI objects.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use UIKit elements in your cocos2d scenes (yes you can mix them). In particular, you can use an UITextField in your game layer:

```
@interface MyLayer : CCLayer<UITextFieldDelegate> {
    UITextField *myTextField;
}
```

Then in the init function of your MyLayer.m:

```
myTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(..,..,..,..)];
myTextField.delegate = self; //set the delegate of the textfield to this layer
[myTextField becomeFirstResponder];

// Configure some of your textfield properties as appropriate...
[myTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
[myTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
[myTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
[myTextField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;

[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview: myTextField];
```

You can then grab the textfield value when the user is done, by implementing the following:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    NSString* myValue = myTextField.text; // get the value and do something
    return YES;
}
```